# Angular js - Services are singleton objects means?

Tags: angularjs, service, singleton

It says that Angular JS Services are singleton objects which are instantiated only once in app.
In terms of instantiation, how different is it from Angular JS factories or controllers?

Answers with a fiddle will be helpful.

Comment: Service is a class or an object, which works on singleton pattern once you create an object of a class the same object will be reused so that the memory utilization is very less. For more details https://www.tutespace.com/2018/11/angularjs-inbuilt-services.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `factory` component in AngularJS. A factory is a function, passed to `module.factory()`, whose responsibility is precisely to *create* the service instance. This factory is called only once by Angular, to create the unique instance of the service. This unique instance, returned by the factory function, is then injected everywhere the service is needed.

So, in short, when you do

```
app.factory('foo', function() {
    var service = {};
    ...
    return service;
});
```

You're not *defining* a factory. You're *passing* a factory function to `app.factory()`, and this factory *creates* and *returns* the service instance. `'foo'` is the name of the service.

A controller is not a singleton at all. Every time `ng-controller="FooCtrl"` is used, or FooCtrl is used in some route or directive, a new instance of `FooCtrl` is created.

Answer (score 0):

Service is a class or an object, which works on singleton pattern once you create an object of a class the same object will be reused so that the memory utilization is very less.